# Can't create UWP app in visual studio 2015 update 3

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp

Please, help me. I try to create new UWP app. I use Visual Studio Community 2015 Update 3. But I get error. [image]

What wrong?

Comment: its hard to say when the error code is Russian :)

Comment: Note that there's also the Russian http://ru.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: Little known, you can [Ctrl]+C on any standard dialog and have it place a text representation in the clipboard. Posting error messages as text is advisable, as it makes them discoverable with text searches.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions on stackoverflow should be in English. Non-English error messages are not helpful to the majority of users.

Comment: I have fixed it by doing this: **1.)** Go to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\ProjectTemplatesCache\CSharp\Windows Root\Windows UAP`. **2.)** Remove the `1031` folder. **3.)** Rename `1033` folder to `1031`.

Comment: I solved this problem. I start work on Visual Studio with English localization. Thanks to all

Answer (score 1):

sometimes updating VS can cause issues, try running the visual studio installer again, Select Modify in the installer, Select "Windows and Web Development" then Remove "Universal Windows App Development Tools" , let it remove and then reinstall.